# grep skips searching in my .bash_profile file

Tags: bash, grep

I want to find where I have exported my CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH variable, so I enter:

```
 grep CPLUS ~
```

but it gives not results, if I enter:

```
 grep CPLUS ~/.bash_profile
```

it works OK, I also tried other commands but with no luck

Comment: use `grep -r CPLUS ~` to recursively search through all files in directory and its sub-directories

Comment: @spasic thank you it worked, without -r what worked was this command: `grep CPLUS ~/.*`